# MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a simple procedure but it can't find a table which I provide in where clause:

```
delimiter //
Create procedure process_order()
begin
    if p.name = 'Memory'
    then
    select 
    r.Name 
    from 
        manufacturers r,
        products p
    where
        r.name = p.Manufacturer and
        r.Code = 1;
    end if;
end;//
```

How can I let mysql know that p is a certain table? Is there a way to declare all tables in the beginning of the program? (without using variables)

Comment: The problem is in the `if` expression, not the `where` clause.  You should describe what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results can really help.

Comment: just selecting a name of a product which must be of type 'memory' and and whose code is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it seems you want something like this:

```
select r.Name 
from manufacturers r join
     products p
     on r.name = p.Manufacturer
where r.Code = 1 and p.name = 'Memory';
```

This seems more useful as a view than as a stored procedure.

Comment: yes but how do I declare p as products before if statement?

Comment: You don't have to write if statement at all, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @MikheilMetreveli . . . Perhaps you want `if exists`.  However, you logic really isn't clear.